# How to get currently focused(active) webpage's DOM tree using javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to make a java software in which I am giving an option to switch to 'Browser' mode. As soon as the user selects it and visits any web page, the user can select any word from the current webpage and see its definition. The user should be able to switch between web pages and still leverage the functionality(and hence the current active web page's DOM tree). Thought of creating a Mozilla or Chrome extension first, but this has to be the part of Java software and browsers these days don't allow installing extension via a software.
I have tried:
`window.document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML` to get all the `<p>` content of the current page but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am confused - is this about Java or JavaScript or both?

Comment: What technology are you using to render the browser? What is the specific error you are seeing? What were you expecting to see?

Comment: @mumpitz as I said this is about the software made in Java where I am trying to call javascript functions. I know that is possible. I wish to have a javascript function which is called when user selects 'Browser' mode from the software and then the JS function should be able to fetch the DOM of active(current focused) web page so that I can get the textual content and apply the searching and highlighting logic.

Comment: @Jamey well I haven't thought of rendering. I thought user should be able to switch from windows to browser tab and work normally. My software window will always stay floating on the screen and then the user must type in the search word (within the textbox of my software) which later gets highlighted and defined on the webpage.

Comment: So you're planning to use something like https://www.seleniumhq.org/ to launch, and drive the browser so that you can inject javascript to allow the user to select a word and see the definition?

Answer (score 1):

To return all the `<p>` contents you can do:

```
var items = [...window.document.getElementsByTagName('p')];
var result = items.map(obj => obj.innerHTML);
```

It will return an array of contents